# How to make submenu for jQuery sliding side menu?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way to make submenu for sliding side menu? 
[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fh6p4/1122/)

```
    <ul id="nav">
        <li><a href="#">Menu Item 1</a></li>
            <ul id="submenu">
                <li><a href="#">Submenu Item 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Submenu Item 2</a></li>
            </ul>
        <li><a href="#">Menu Item 2</a></li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: That's not valid markup. You can't have a `ul` as a child of another `ul`.

Comment: At least this [page](http://csswizardry.com/demos/css-dropdown/) was validated by W3C

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<kbd>[**Fiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/fh6p4/1123/)</kbd>

**Changed Markup**

added `ul` instead of `li`  as `ul` can not directly contain `ul`

```
<div id="menu">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Menu Item 1</a>

            <ul id="submenu"> <!-- added ul instead of li -->
                <li><a href="#">Submenu Item 1</a>

                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Submenu Item 2</a>

                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu Item 2</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu Item 3</a>

        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="right">
    <button type="button" id="button">Menu</button>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$('#menu li:has("ul")').children('ul').hide(); //hide submenu
$('#button').toggle(
function () {
    $('#right').animate({
        left: 150
    });
},
function () {
    $('#right').animate({
        left: 0
    });
});
$('#menu li:has("ul")').click(function(){ 
    $(this).children('ul').slideToggle(); //toggle submenu
});
```

References

[.slideToggle()](http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/)

[:has()](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/)